# php - 000webhost 500 internal server error and application error

Tags: php, android, webserver

so i was following a video uploading image from android to server, but im using the web server called "000webhost", i tested the url and it gives me a generic error "Application error". so i tested it on postman, now it gives me "500 Internal Server Error", i removed the header and the error was gone on both sides but it doesn't do anything.

```
<?php

 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){
    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0){
        $connection = new mysqli('localhost','id7794597_razzlesz','hahayz9090','id7794597_memes');
        $query = "INSERT INTO photos (name,path) values ('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if($result){
            echo "success";
            }else{
                echo "failed";
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Are you using the "free" hosting? If so, you will not be able to use the hosting service remotely.

Answer (score -1):

You need to debug further what is causing the error. I am pretty sure the file you're uploading is too big, it either exceeds the server limits in terms of size or timeout.

In order to debug you need to look at the PHP error logs. I don't know your hosting platform, but from a quick google it looks like you need to enable the PHP logs from the .htaccess.

Please read the following: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/where-are-the-server-logs-and-php-logs-and-can-i-access-them/66879